# What is a "bounty" on a question? How can I start a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

If you're new around here, or else you haven't yet seen a bounty question, you might be wondering "What is a bounty?"

Essentially, if you asked a question and it isn't getting very much attention, the first thing you should do is try and make it a *better question*.  Once you've done that, another option is the **bounty**.  A bounty involves offering up some of your own reputation as additional incentive to get a question answered.

You can start a bounty on your own questions (most common), and even on questions asked by other people, perhaps on interesting but [unanswered questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/unanswered) you can't answer yourself.

One requirement for adding a bounty is that the question be at least two days old. If a question is eligible to have a bounty, you'll notice a *"start bounty"* link under the question's comments.  (It's a small link, easy to miss.)  You also must have at least 75 reputation.

As a demonstration of this feature we, your moderators, have started bounties on a handful of open questions that we think deserve more attention.  You'll find questions having a bounty on the **[Featured](https://money.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)** page for 7 days.  They'll also appear in the regular question lists with a special icon displaying the outstanding bounty amount.

Got any additional things to say about the bounty system?  Feel free to answer below.

Comment: There's also a lot of guidance about bounties [on the bounty privilege page](http://money.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: It's definitely a good idea to have some FAQ entries here on meta for recurring questions that come up about the site, answering in the context of the site. The main Meta SO contains a vast amount of knowledge that can be rather difficult to find. But, should probably move the bulk of the answer you posted in the question to an actual answer, just to alleviate confusion and create an editable answer resource.